# Network share between two WiFi routers that are connected by Ethernet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking, wired-networking

I'd like to be able to connect between two computers that exist on separate WiFi networks (things like Samba sharing, UPNP node control, etc. - basically, all the usual LAN things). The key thing is that the two WiFi routers are physically connected by an Ethernet cable, but the devices are physically too far apart to be connected on the same WiFi network. Both WiFi networks get their internet connection from one of the routers.

Is there some way of either unifying the network, so that everyone is connected together, or otherwise setting up a some sort of 'bridge' (I have no idea if this term is suitable) to connect the required machines up?

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you have one Wi-Fi router with an Internet connection, and an Ethernet cable going from there to a second Wi-Fi router?

If so, then the solution is just to configure the second Wi-Fi router as a simple bridge from Ethernet to Wi-Fi instead of acting as a full router/NAT gateway. On most consumer home Wi-Fi gateways, this means disabling the DHCP service and connecting the Ethernet cable to a LAN port instead of the WAN port. (Some Wi-Fi routers let you disable NAT and DHCP service, which makes the WAN port automatically become a LAN port, so if that's the case with your product, do that.)

Once the secondary router is just bridging traffic between LAN and WLAN, all of your WLAN and LAN clients of either router will be on the same network (a hybrid LAN/WLAN network), and will be able to see each other via LAN discovery protocols and everything.